# Embedding of the rationals

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that it's impossible to embed the set of rationals $Q$ in a complete metric countable space.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is an uncountable cardinal of rational Cauchy sequences with different limits and which would have to converge to an uncountable cardinal of *different* limits...and I bet you can construct these ones.